# Need to understand IE conditional comments inside the HTML5-boilerplate

Tags: html, internet-explorer, comments, conditional-statements, html5boilerplate

I couldn't understand one place in IE conditional comments in the HTML5-boilerplate.
It's about this part:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

The following two cases are quite straightforward,

1. in cases of IE6/7, the condition "if gt IE 8" is FALSE, so it outputs `<!-- -->`;
2. in cases of non-IE, "[if gt IE8]" and "[endif]" are not recognized, "`<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->`" and "`<!--<![endif]-->`" are therefore standard HTML comments. So it outputs `<html class="no-js">`;

What confuses me is the case of IE9.
In case of IE9, the condition "if gt IE 8" is TRUE, so it outputs the body of IE condition:

```
<!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--
```

1. `<!-->` is empty comment;
2. `<html class="no-js">` is regular HTML output;

But what about the ending "`<!--`"? How is it handled? In my opinion, this beginning comment tag will turn everything following it into comments until it meets an end tag "`-->`". Isn't this a huge problem?

But I have never seen anybody questioning about this. So am I missing something?
Can somebody explain this to me? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `<!-->` is not an empty HTML comment. An empty comment would have four minus signs.

Comment: Lister: then how do you think IE9 parses <!--> <html class="no-js"> <!-- ?

Comment: **Imp. Note**: MS has dropped the support of conditional comments starting IE 10. More details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735840/why-are-conditional-comments-in-html-not-recognized-in-internet-explorer-11-is)

Answer (score 2):

> In case of IE9, the condition "if gt IE 8" is TRUE

Indeed - so what happens is that whereas the comment is considered like so by other versions of IE:

```
<!--[if not my version]>
    Remove/ignore everything
<![endif]-->
```

Or simply:

```
""
```

For IE9 the conditional comments are treated just like any other comment:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <html class="no-js"> 
<!--<![endif]-->
```

I.e the (exploded) first and last lines are complete comments themselves

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
^ start of a comment
    ^.............^ content not relevant
                   ^ end of a comment - first occurrence of `-->`
```

Therefore the browser (be it IE9+ or not-internet explorer) sees only:

```
<html class="no-js">
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't point to any actual reference for how they parse these (CC have always been sparsely documented) and can't remember who came up with this pattern, but IE isn't passed `<!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--` it's passed only `<html class="no-js">` It combines each full, valid comment block as the start and end of the conditional comments.

Here's an example that shows it's not passed an open comment

http://htmlcssjavascript.com/samples/cc.html

```
<!--[if IE 8]>        <p>IE8</p> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <p>IE9+</p> <!--<![endif]-->
Not an open comment
-->
```

That outputs....

"IE9+

Not an open comment -->"

in IE9. If it left a comment open, of couse, the "Not an open comment" bit would disappear.

Comment: Sorry I played around with it after I tested it. I'll adjust back to the original example.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, I figured out a different way to illustrate what happens.