# Why are conditional comments in HTML not recognized in Internet Explorer 11? Is it not supported now?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, conditional-comments

I want to display different content on different browsers. I used Internet Explorer 11 and Google Chrome 39. But, in Internet Explorer and all other browsers "Not Internet Explorer" is displayed. Is something wrong with the code? I saw the following code as an answer to one of the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805189/html-ie-conditional-statement-not-working-with-chrome-firefox) , then why it is not working now?

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!--[if (IE)]><p>This is Internet Explorer</p><![endif]-->

<!--[if !(IE)]><!--> Not Internet Explorer <!--<![endif]-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `[...]Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer 10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and compliance with HTML5.[...]` [MSDN: Conditional comments are no longer supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: ^-- yup.  Conditionals are only supported by IE 9 and below.  Might I suggest using [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) instead?  It's a javascript library for feature detection, which is preferable to version detection.

Comment: A Google search for "conditional comments IE11" returns as the first result the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. PS. I may be mistaken, but I seem to recall that these comments were senstive to newlines in the right places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Microsoft dropped conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Internet Explorer as of version 10.

Comment: @RBT Well, it would have been a welcome decision, if it weren’t for the fact that they’re still needed. As it is, it just gives developers extra trouble. :-/